# Use of Scanner class in recursive functions

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to use a recursive method/function, which uses the Scanner class. Closing the scanner, causes an exception to be thrown the next time the same method is called within the recursion. A workaround to this is not to close the scanner at all, but this is not a right approach. I suspect the same scanner object is used between recursive calls, so that's why closing it creates havoc. If my assumption is correct then closing the scanner in the last method call would be a valid workaround (i.e. no actual resource leak). Is there anything I may be missing before jumping into Scanner and related implementation code?

**EDIT**

The answers provided were really useful and enlightening. In summary, the problem is the constant re-opening and closing of the scanner, and not recursion per se. The reason I would avoid passing the scanner object as parameter is that this example simulates a larger project, calling multiple recursive functions and I would have to pass the scanner object in all of them.

On the practical side, and from the answers provided, I think just closing the scanner in the last recursive call would work without having any resource leaks. Any related opinions would be welcome, esp. if you see something wrong with my approach.

Here is an example of my initial experiment:

```
package scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void acceptValidInput() {

    System.out.print("Enter a number greater than 10: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = sc.nextInt();

    // Adding this will make an exception to be thrown:
    sc.close();

    if (i <= 10) {
        acceptValidInput();
    }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    acceptValidInput();
    System.out.println("Your input is valid");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not create and close (if you really want to; it won't matter for System.in) the `Scanner` in `main`, and pass it to `acceptValidInput` as a parameter? As an aside, I wouldn't use recursion here anyway.

Comment: I see now, that recursion is not the problem but rather the opening and closing within the scope of the same program? I tried the same experiment with two different methods and it still failed the same way. The main solution proposed of passing the scanner as parameter works, but in the same way closing the scanner after I am done with recursive calls would be equally right, as I need to close it only 'once'. This is extracted from a bigger project, where it makes sense (I think) to use recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you start to consume an input stream using a `Scanner`, you should not try to read from it in any other way anymore. In other words, after you have constructed a `Scanner` to read from `System.in`, you need to use it for all further reading from `System.in`. This is because [`Scanner` buffers input](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Scanner.java#838), so you have no idea how much input it has already consumed but not emitted yet.

Therefore, I recommend that you construct one `Scanner`, then use it for all the reading:

```
public class Main {
  public static void acceptValidInput(Scanner sc) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number greater than 10: ");

    int i = sc.nextInt();

    if (i <= 10) {
      acceptValidInput(sc);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    acceptValidInput(sc);
    System.out.println("Your input is valid");
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works:

```
package scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void acceptValidInput(Scanner sc) {

        int i = sc.nextInt();

        if (i <= 10) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number greater than 10: ");

            acceptValidInput(sc);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter a number greater than 10: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        acceptValidInput(sc);
        sc.close();

        System.out.println("Your input is valid");
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Enter a number greater than 10: 4
Enter a number greater than 10: 5
Enter a number greater than 10: 11
Your input is valid

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing the scanner closes also the underlying input stream. In this case it is the System.in stream - you shouldn't do this. Either do not close it or create a single scanner for all method calls.

Comment: "Either do not close it" I think that's a bad idea because `Scanner` buffers input – see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Scanner.java .

Comment: Good point. I think the System.in stream should then be wrapped in a stream class that avoids that the underlying stream is actually closed.

Comment: Maybe. The best approach for a command line tool would probably to use just a single instance of the Scanner using System.in instead of creating them for each method call.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class abc{
public void acceptValidInput() {

    System.out.print("Enter a number greater than 10: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = sc.nextInt();

    // Adding this will make an exception to be thrown:


    if (i <= 10) {
        acceptValidInput();
    }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     while(true){
      abc a=new abc();
   a.acceptValidInput();
   System.out.println("Your input is valid");
     }
  }}
```

try this.

Comment: As far as I can see, it's somewhat flaky though: If two lines come in in one read, the second line would be ignored because it has been buffered by the first `Scanner`.

Comment: but this case is not here otherwise i use bufferreader. I only concentrate on functionality.

Comment: But you don't close the scanner (you removed the line doing it). That was my initial point.