# Scanner.nextInt() throwing NoSuchElementException after InputMismatchException

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a `getInt()` method, which abstracts the extraction of an integer from the console, to the rest of my program.

Inside, is a try using resource -- the resource being a scanner; with a catch block for the inevitable `InputMismatchException`.

It captures valid inputs, fine; and catches false inputs.

However, after -- recursively -- trying to again capture the input, my scanner instantly throws a `NoSuchElementException`, which is obviously linked to the last mismatch error.

Do I need to clear something in the second scanner, perhaps left from the first?

---

```
private static int getInt(String name) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.printf("Enter %s: ", name);
        return scanner.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
        return getInt(name);
    }
}
```

---

I already tried to instantiate the scanner out of the function, like so:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
getInt(scanner, name);

...

private static int getInt(Scanner scanner, String name) {
    try {
        System.out.printf("Enter %s: ", name);
        return scanner.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
        return getInt(scanner, name);
    }
}
```

Here, I simply get a stack over flow error, because the mismatch error recurs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of Scanner class in recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322686/use-of-scanner-class-in-recursive-functions)

Comment: @GBlodgett I tried taking the scanner outside, while debugging, and i get the same error. I'll edit with question with what happens

Comment: Pass it as a parameter. Also you'll need to call `next()` in your catch block to clear the bad input

Comment: I am.. I get a stackoverflow error instead, because you just get the error Over and over till the stack fills up.

Comment: No you get it because you never call `next()` to clear the bad input

Comment: After your println in your catch block add `scanner.next();`

Comment: You see, that's exactly what I meant by `Do I need to clear something in the second scanner, perhaps left from the first?` Thanks